# How to add CSV File to Tabulator AJAXURL

Tags: ajax, csv, tabulator

i have created a code which should display the content of a csv file using a tabulator , I did the code in accordance with some tutorial videos .  but still am not getting the data displayed . am not getting any error also .. Can anyone help me .

```
import xlsx from "xlsx";
import feather from "feather-icons";
import Tabulator from "tabulator-tables";

(function (cash) {
    "use strict";

    // Tabulator
    if (cash("#tabulator").length) {
        // Setup Tabulator
        let table = new Tabulator("#tabulator", {
            ajaxURL: "C:/Users/Desktop/All Desktop File/GARRS.csv",
            ajaxFiltering: true,
            ajaxSorting: true,
            printAsHtml: true,
            printStyled: true,
            pagination: "remote",
            paginationSize: 10,
            paginationSizeSelector: [10, 20, 30, 40],
            layout: "fitColumns",
            responsiveLayout: "collapse",
            placeholder: "No matching records found",
            columns: [
                {
                    formatter: "responsiveCollapse",
                    width: 40,
                    minWidth: 30,
                    align: "center",
                    resizable: false,
                    headerSort: false,
                },  
                {
                    title: "PRODUCT NAME",
                    minWidth: 200,
                    responsive: 0,
                    field: "name",
                    vertAlign: "middle",
                    print: false,
                    download: false,
                    formatter(cell, formatterParams) {
                        return `<div>
                            <div class="font-medium whitespace-nowrap">${
                                cell.getData().name
                            }</div>
                            <div class="text-gray-600 text-xs whitespace-nowrap">${
                                cell.getData().category
                            }</div>
                        </div>`;
                    },
                },
```

Is there anyway to do this . and am getting no error with this too , so i don know what really is the problem .

Am new to this , kindly help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are in luck, up until the 5.1 release this was not possible, Tabulator could only accept JSON formatted data or arrays.

Tabulator 5.1 introduced the [Import Module](http://tabulator.info/docs/5.1/data#import) that allows exactly the type of import you are looking for.

To start with you seem to be trying to load from a local file on your `C:\` that will not work in browser in that manor and is bad practice anyway because it wont work when deployed to the server.

If you want to pick the file from a file picker you can call the `import` function on the table

```js
table.import("csv", ".csv");
```

If you already have the csv formatted data in a string this can be loaded into the table on the `data` option as follows:

```js
//define some CSV data
var csvData = `"Name", "Location", "Age"
"Oli", "London", "23"
"Jim", "Mancheser", "53"`;

//define table
var table = new Tabulator("#example-table", {
    data:csvData,
    importFormat:"csv",
    autoColumns:true,
});
```