# Loading .csv file automatically - Tabulator

Tags: tabulator

I am currently loading a .csv file via fgetcsv into a table, then using the Load Data from HTML to show the data in Tabulator.  After looking at the question here: [How to add CSV File to Tabulator AJAXURL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67014787/how-to-add-csv-file-to-tabulator-ajaxurl)  I see that a user can load a .csv manually, but is there a way to call that automatically off the webserver to load into Tabulator?  What I am doing now works fine, but just looking to clean up the HTML.

```
<table id="data-table" class="w3-center">
    <?php
        $datei = '../Data/Arrests/2006Arrests.csv';
        $open = fopen($datei, "r");
        $zeile = 0;
        while (($data = fgetcsv($open, 10000, ","))) {
        if ($zeile == 0) {
        echo '<thead hidden>';
        }
        elseif ($zeile == 1) {
        echo '</thead><tbody hidden>';
        }
        echo '<tr>' . "\n";
        for ( $x= 0; $x< count($data); $x++) {
        if ($zeile == 0) {
        echo '<th>'.$data[$x].'</th>' . "\n";
        } else
        echo '<td>'.$data[$x].'</td>' . "\n";
        }
        $zeile++;
        echo '</tr>'. "\n";
        }
        fclose($open);
        echo  '</tbody>';
    ?>
</table>
<script>
    var table = new Tabulator("#data-table", {
        pagination:"local",
        paginationSize:12,
        height:"455",
        movableColumns:true,
        layout:"fitDataFill",
        columns:[
            {title:"Date",field:"Date", headerFilter:"input"},
            {title:"Time",field:"Time", headerFilter:"input",responsive:2},
            {title:"Age",field:"Age",headerFilter:"input",align:"center", width:70},
            {title:"Sex",field:"Sex", headerFilter:"input", width:70},
            {title:"Race",field:"Race", headerFilter:"input", width:70},
            {title:"City",field:"city", headerFilter:"input", width:70},
            {title:"State",field:"state", headerFilter:"input", width:70},
            {title:"Statute",field:"Statute", headerFilter:"input", width:150},
            {title:"Offense",field:"Offense", headerFilter:"input",formatter:"html",tooltip:true, width:300},
            {title:"Incident #",field:"Incident #", headerFilter:"input"},
            ],
    });
</script>
```